# "the art and animation is" or "the art and animation are"

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number, tenses, compound-subjects

I'm unsure whether I should use "are" or "is" in the following sentence:

"The art and animation in particular are incredible."

or

"The art and animation in particular is incredible."

I'm sort of interpreting "art and animation" as a singular noun, since I'm referring to "art and animation" as one category to be evaluated. Is this a contextual thing where either one could be correct? I'm leaning towards "is," but I'm just not sure if that's right and am beginning to feel illiterate.

I tried to look up example sentences with both "is" and "are" inserted into "The art and animation ___," but I wasn't able to conclude much from it.

Comment: I cannot think of a context where *art and animation* would be singular.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since you're referring to "art and animation" as one category to be evaluated, the following one is correct;

> The art and animation in particular is incredible.

and not the other one which is;

> The art and animation in particular are incredible.

and this one would be correct when you're referring to "art" and "animation" as two different categories and following would be correct way of quoting it;

> The art and **the** animation in particular are incredible.